# Im trying to import a game class and i get this message when i startup "Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference."?

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm making an app for an assignment and i'm importing this game onto a page for some to click on a button at the game pops up. But i get this error and i've searched online and people say it could be anything..... I'm a beginner at AS3 so i'm not good at coding, but does anyone know why this is happening?

I would like the bottle to be in a random order but I'll have to come to that when it appears for me.

Here's the code:

```
package {

import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.Event;

public class Shoot extends MovieClip {

    private var bottleArray:Array = new Array();
    private var numOfBottle:uint = 9;
    private var bottleHit:uint = 0;
    private var hits:uint = 6;
    private var bg:Sprite;

    var bottle:MovieClip = new Bottle
    var shots:MovieClip = new Shots
    var endBox:MovieClip = new EndBox

    public function Shoot() {

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterHandler);


       //Adds the bottles onto the stage.
       for (var i:int = 0; i < numOfBottle; i++) {
        bottle.x = 0 + (i * 200);
        bottle.y = 344.35;
        bottle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
        addChild(bottle);
        bottleArray.push(bottle);
       }

       //Adds a invisibe background to detect when the targets have been missed.
       bg = new Sprite();
       bg.graphics.beginFill(0x000000,0);
       bg.graphics.drawRect(0, 0, stage.stageWidth, stage.stageHeight);
       bg.graphics.endFill();
       addChildAt(bg,0);
       bg.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkShots);

       //Adds the number shot left to stage. 
       shots.x = 480;
       shots.y = 80;
       addChild(shots);

       addChild(endBox);
       endBox.x = 220;
       endBox.y = 550;
       endBox.visible = false;

      }


      //This function moves all the bottles in the array four pixels to the 
      //right at the current frame rate. If a bottle goes passed the stage 
      //width, it will get re-added a bottle width before the start of the stage.
    function enterHandler(e:Event):void{
       for (var j:uint = 0; j <  bottleArray.length; j++) {
        bottleArray[j].x +=  1;

        if (bottleArray[j].x > stage.stageWidth + bottleArray[j].width) {
         bottleArray[j].x = 0 - bottleArray[j].width;
        }
       }
      }


      //This removes the bottle from the stage, the event listener and 
      //removes it from the array if it has been clicked. 
      function clickHandler(e:MouseEvent):void {
       var index:uint = bottleArray.indexOf(e.currentTarget);
       var target:MovieClip = e.currentTarget as MovieClip;

       target.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
       removeChild(target);
       bottleArray.splice(index, 1);

       checkShots();
      }


      function checkShots(e:MouseEvent = null):void{
       //This increments the bottleHit counter by one and goes to 
       //the next frame in shots movie clip.
       bottleHit++;
       shots.gotoAndStop(shots.currentFrame + 1);


       //If there are no more shot available and array length is six then you win. 
       if (shots.currentFrame == shots.totalFrames && bottleArray.length == hits) {
        removeObject();
        endBox.visible = true;
        endBox.gotoAndStop(1);
       }
       //If there are no more shot available you lose.
       else if (shots.currentFrame == shots.totalFrames) {
        removeObject();
        endBox.visible = true;
        endBox.gotoAndStop(2);
       }
      }

      //This removes the event listeners
      function removeObject():void{
       removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, enterHandler);
       bg.removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, checkShots);

       for (var i:int = 0; i < bottleArray.length; i++){
        bottleArray[i].removeEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler);
       }
      }
     }
    }
```

Comment: what's the line number associated with the 'null object reference' error?

Comment: Line 32 and 62.

Comment: Try removing all of your code after line 67. Comment-out your references to 'shots' and 'endBox' and the CLICK listener for 'checkShots'. Do you still get the 'null object' error?

Answer (score 2):

One obvious problem is that you're instantiating only one bottle! You need to declare:

```
var bottle:MovieClip;
```

as an instance variable and then add this line to your 'for' loop:

```
bottle = new Bottle;
```

so that you will actually have 9 bottles to talk about later!

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem. ENTER_FRAME event will be handled in the beginning of next frame anyway.

Comment: Correct! But you might have contributed SOMETHING about the actual problem!

Comment: What does this mean?  shots.gotoAndStop(shots.currentFrame + 1);

Comment: Basically, i have 3 shots, and on the timeline of the object 'shots' there is 3 key frames and each key frame a ball is subtracted. So when you shoot it looks like you're actually shooting bullets. That make sense

Comment: @Craig you asked the correct question about the line no. that throws the error so I just pointed the obvious mislead. Otherwise you've got it covered =^_^=

Comment: The root of OP's problem is indeed here, because the same `bottle` gets pushed into an array nine times, then an attempt of `removechild()` is done also 9 times, which will eventually arise a "not a child" runtime error anyway. However, a check of `index` being -1 in `clickHandler` is also missing, more, since `index` is uint, it'll overload with -1 returned from `indexOf()` and result in `bottleArray[index]` being null.